# R changes referent for a factor ONLY in interaction term

Tags: r, linear-regression

Been using R for many years, but need help solving this.

I set up a factor using "2" as the referent

```
newdat$time.f<-factor(newdat$time,levels=c(2,0,1,3,4,5),
                      labels=c("preevent","pre2","pre1","post1","post2","post3"))
```

Then I ran a cross-level econometric model (event study Different-in-Difference). Note I don't include the main effect for "treated" because it is invariant across entities and factor(entity) accounts for the variance:

```
tmod2<-lm(outcome2~time.f+treated:time.f+factor(entity),newdat)
summary(tmod2)$coef
```

Notice the main effects for time.f reflect the referent I have set up (e.g., pre2 vs prevent, etc.). All good so far.

```
> summary(tmod2)$coef
                           Estimate Std. Error      t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)             3.613587845  0.7316227  4.939141003 1.437147e-05
time.fpre2             -0.288572099  0.5018891 -0.574971890 5.685305e-01
time.fpre1             -0.316279381  0.5018891 -0.630177880 5.321620e-01
time.fpost1            -0.455537159  0.5018891 -0.907645135 3.695017e-01
time.fpost2             0.129416391  0.5018891  0.257858563 7.978381e-01
time.fpost3            -0.835905832  0.5018891 -1.665519150 1.036235e-01
```

However, further down in the same results the interaction term is switched to a referent of post3 and pre-event is added back in (what I'm showing below is the SAME model results as above, just trying to reduce screen clutter).

```
time.fpreevent:treated -3.196528836  0.7935563 -4.028106063 2.443035e-04
time.fpre2:treated     -4.160157423  0.7935563 -5.242422702 5.452540e-06
time.fpre1:treated     -2.730869474  0.7935563 -3.441305381 1.368885e-03
time.fpost1:treated    -3.103561272  0.7935563 -3.910952979 3.473610e-04
time.fpost2:treated    -1.979244438  0.7935563 -2.494145033 1.685859e-02
```

Any thoughts?  I can get the correct answer if I dummy code time and omit the dummy code for pre-event and specify the model as:

```
tmod<-lm(outcome2~period_pre_2 + period_pre_1 + period_post_1 + period_post_2 + period_post_3+
           treated:period_pre_2+treated:period_pre_1+  treated:period_post_1+ 
           treated:period_post_2+treated:period_post_3+factor(entity),newdat)
```

This is just a "clunky" solution (in my mind), and I don't understand why R would use my specified referent for the main-effects, but switch referents for the interaction.

Thanks!

Here is the data used in the example above. Simple. Just for a class demo.

```
dput(newdat)
structure(list(entity = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), time = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), post = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), treated = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), outcome = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), outcome2 = c(-1.207065749, 0.277429242, 1.084441177, 
-1.345697703, 2.429124689, 3.506055892, -0.57473996, -0.546631856, 
-0.564451999, 0.109962171, 1.5228073, 2.001613555, -0.776253895, 
0.064458817, 0.959494059, 0.889714506, 1.488990494, 2.088804583, 
-0.83717168, 2.415835178, 0.13408822, 0.509314103, 1.559452128, 
3.459589441, -0.693720247, -1.44820491, 0.574755721, -1.023655723, 
-0.0151383, -0.935948601, 1.102297546, -0.475593079, -0.709440038, 
-0.501258061, -1.629093469, -1.167619262, -2.180039649, -1.340993192, 
-0.294293859, -0.46589754, 1.449496265, -1.068642724, -0.855364634, 
-0.280623002, -0.994340076, -0.968514318, -1.107318193, -1.251985886, 
-0.523828119, -0.496849957, -1.806031257, -0.582075925, -1.108889624, 
-1.014962009, -0.162309524, 0.563055819, 1.647817473, -0.773353424, 
1.605909629, -1.157808548), period_pre_2 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), period_pre_1 = c(0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), period_event = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), period_post_1 = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), period_post_2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), period_post_3 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), time.f = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L), levels = c("preevent", 
"pre2", "pre1", "post1", "post2", "post3"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.